# Java How to send an email/sms from a Users computer

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to send a User an email or SMS to his SmartPhone when an Alert happens on his desktop App.

How can I send an email WITHOUT supplying my log-in credentials within the App?

using smtp I need to provide my credentials, but as this is for a published application that does not sound like a good idea.

I understand this is a very general question, but I am having trouble finding a solution on the web.

Comment: we could use some more details i think

Comment: Use a web service that you control.

Comment: You could define the use of some kind of web based SMTP service, such as gmail, but you would still need to supply the credentials to that service (but if you set up a special account for it, you could simply supply the credentials internally to the program).

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thats my current solution but I was wondering if there was something smarter

Comment: Almost all SMTP servers will require some kind authentication, unless you would like to set one up and allow anybody to send through it...which I'm sure we all we just love :P

Comment: maybe this helps http://www.mailgun.com/ (you need an api key but some kind of authentication you cannot circumvent)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you will not be able to do this, as the smtp server requires some sort of authentication, from which to send from